# Set default for a prop that has different types in VueJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

New to Vue.js. I want a prop that can accept either a string, number, or Boolean. And I want the default to be null. Not sure if this is the best approach but I'm using this prop for a form that has different types for different sections. Thus, I would like that flexibility. This is what I have

```
props: {
  value: [String, Number, Boolean]
}
```

Not sure where or how to put the default value. I couldn't find the info in the documentation.

I've tried different syntaxes but can't find the right one. Here's an example.

```
props: {
  value: { type: String || Number || Boolean, default: null }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gfoj0ke/3/)

Comment: @Sphinx That works perfectly! Thanks! Can't believe I wasn't able to figure that one out. :P